# What is the best approach for handling a complex form in html?

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp, ria

I need to implement a webform (JSP, struts) featuring loads of checkboxes and textfields. Basically I have a tree made of checkboxes which has to be extendable (like adding a new node). On another page the same data is used, but refined. So you add again child nodes to the mentioned data structure using textboxes etc. I can describe the datastructure in XML:

  
    
      
        
      
    
  

But contains about 100 rows in reality.

I found 3 approaches:
1. Do a webform in JSP which lowers the user experience because lots of postbacks are necessary (every time i add/edit/delete a node, subnode...)
2. do it in async fashion. -> loads of javascript to handle the structure of the data (keep the XML data in a hidden div and update ui)
3. go for a RIA like OpenLaszlo

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know OpenLaszlo, go for it. You will end up with a better user experience with less work.

You should target user interface and performance when developing an app. So IMO, plain JSP will be my last approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider client side rendering.
It allows to build very responsive web apps:

- build your JSP pages to deliver JSON data, no HTML here
- use a javascript templating engine in the browser to convert the data in HTML client side. I'm the author of [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure) but there are plenty of others on the web that may suit better your style
- when the user types or press submit, parse the form using a common technique found in many frameworks.
   i.e: the "name" attribute is the path to set the value in the JSON
  `<input name="employee.name" type="text" ... />`
- When the form is parsed, post back the JSON to a JSP page that will read it and do the backend work.

You can use XML instead of JSON and XSLT instead of a JS templating engine, but if you target the web browser only, it adds an extra layer of complexity and trouble to parse the XML.